# how to change a value of a php variable with ajax or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so I make a small php app and I try to use ajax.
I have two lists :

```
 <select name="auteur" id="auteur" >
                <option value='-1'>Aucun auteur</option>
                <?php
                require("bd/bd.inc.php");
                $resA = listeAuteurs();
                while ($rowA = $resA->fetch()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $rowA["id"] . "'>" . $rowA["nom"] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

And

```
<select id="livre" name="livre">
                    <option value="-1">
                        Aucun livre
                    </option>
                    <?php
                    $idAuteur = NULL;
                require("bd/bd.inc.php");
                $resL = listeLivres($idAuteur);
                while ($rowL = $resL->fetch()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $rowL["idLivre"] . "'>" . $rowL["titre"] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
```

In my ajax.js file I get the value of the slected option of the first list with this code :`var validauteur = $( "#auteur" ).val();`

And what I want is to modify the value of the variable "$idAuteur" in the second list with the value of the selected option of the first list.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Show us your AJAX code

Comment: are these two lists in one php file?

Comment: yes two list in one php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use AJAX to edit the PHP variable of a page that has already loaded - but you can use AJAX to trigger a JS function (on success) which will edit the second input.

In your AJAX success return, add some JS code to edit the second select box:

```
$( "#livre" ).html(...);
```

What you actually want to change it to is upto you.